# How to hide pages based on a custom authentication

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

i have a custom authentication which i will put in the code section below based on 2 tables, an employee table and an employer table. When an employer logs in, they can see their bank details and a list of all the employee reports. When an employee logs in i want the employer bank details page to be hidden and the list of all employee page to also be hidden and i want the employee's details page to be shown instead. Im not sure how to do this at all. The closest thing ive found was a custom authorisation scheme but that required the DB admin having to manually grant users permissions.

A key note) I as the database administrator do not want to have to manually grant permissions to certain users. Employers and employees will make their own account and depending on whether they are an employer or employee (which the authentication scheme should do) the appropriate pages should be shown. (So yes, an employee could lie about being an employer when making an account but ignore that)

Another note) Please ignore the fact that passwords are stored in plain text, this is a homework problem and encryption has not been taught yet.

```
function authenticate( p_username varchar2, p_password varchar2 ) return boolean is  
begin  
  return(  
     Table1Authenticate( p_username, p_password )  
     or  
     Table2Authenticate( p_username, p_password )  
   );  
end; 


create or replace function Table1Authenticate( p_username varchar2, p_password varchar2 ) return boolean is  
   i integer;  
begin  
   select  
      1 into i  
  from employer  
  where upper(employer.username) = upper(p_username)  
  and   upper(employer.passwords) = upper(p_password);  
  return( true );  
exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then  
  return( false );  
end;

create or replace function Table2Authenticate( p_username varchar2, p_password varchar2 ) return boolean is  
   i integer;  
begin  
   select  
      1 into i  
  from employee
  where upper(employee.username) = upper(p_username)  
  and   upper(employee.password) = upper(p_password);  
  return( true );  
exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then  
  return( false );  
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle Apex, you can restrict the page access using `Page > Security > Authorization Scheme`. You can create custom function returning boolean as a custom Authorization Scheme in the `Shared Components > Authorization Schemes` and used in the pages required. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, im not sure how to make a function returning boolean for this since i copied the authentication scheme i have above form a website and changed it to fit my table. I also tried making an exists authorisation but it seems that this still allows employees to click on an employer page but they will get an error pop up that denies them from accessing this page. Instead of this i want the whole page to be hidden in the navigation bar so that they cant even see it or click on it.

Comment: Hi, Now your requirement is clear. To hide the Employer/Employee from the navigation bar, Go to specific `Shared Components > Navigation Bar List > Select List Entry > Conditions` and you can select the conditions whichever suits your requirement and enter the action to be done in `Expression1`. For instance, you can select `PLSQL Function Returning boolean` as condition and copy your function in `Expression 1`. So based on the boolean return, Menu will appear/disappear. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As similarly discussed in the response to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378000/making-a-custom-authentication-based-on-2-different-types-of-users-in-apex/55380129#55380129), you would define pages appropriate to each type of user, and protect these pages & the links to them using Authorisation Schemes.

You can empower users to maintain a set of records that determines the type of access each user has, and restrict access to that page accordingly. This way the DBA can stay focussed on keeping the hardward spinning (that's a joke).

This is **not** an authentication problem. It's a question of privileges, once you're in.

Analogy: Can I log into my bank? Sure. What can I do when I get there - only what any customer can do, with only their accounts. That's authentication, privileges and row level security in action, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be best served by having the authentication you are doing triggering a dynamic action, which then hides the employer bank details table.
Perhaps have the authentication set value to a hidden item(employer or employee) and set a dynamic action based on the value of the item.
To be a bit safer, set the dynamic action to if employer, true : show table employer bank details, false: hide table employer bank details, and make only the false action execute on load.
This should hopefully work

EDIT: Damn, I hadnt read the question well enough I guess. I was thinking you wanted tables on one page. So nevermind

Comment: Don't use dynamic actions to secure components on a page, otherwise these actions can be reversed using browser based tools on the client. Use Server Side Conditions instead, or assign Authorisation scheme.